# publish multiple mqtt topics, in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

So I am trying to publish messages to an mqtt broker, in a format like this,
This is meant to show how it looks like in an mqtt explorer:

```
ipaddress
 |
  deviceid
  |
   info
   |
    name=Devices[0].deviceName
```

In my code this is what I have at the moment(relevant bits only):

```
let mqtt=require('mqtt')
let client=mqtt.connect('ipaddress)

client.on('connect', function(){
  var options={
    retain:true,
    qos:0
  };

  client.subscribe('+/info/#')

  client.publish(Devices[0].deviceName,'',options)
}
```

What I end up getting with this is:

```
ipaddress
 |
  deviceid
   |
    info=Devices[0].deviceName
```

Comment: Should the `'devicename'` really be in quotes or is it meant to point to a string that hold `ipaddress/deviceid/info/name`?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it is pointing to a variable which contains a string,

Comment: Please edit the question to make that clear

Comment: I've changed it where it takes the device from JSON object.

Comment: Yes but without knowing what is actually in that variable it doesn't help us answer your question

Comment: yeah so the variable just contains a string of random letters an numbers, in this case its, '1231prtuv'

Comment: Since `client.publish()` takes arguments in the order topic, payload, options I'm really struggling to see what your question is here. You've just said the topic you are publishing to is `1231prtuv` (and an empty topic) This will clear the retained message at that topic.

Comment: Yeah so basically when publishing, deviceid should actually be Devices[0].deviceName, I just didn't want to confuse you. When I click the device id(Devices[0].deviceName) I get a drop-down which says, info=Devices[0].deviceName. But what I want to do is have another dropdown for after that for info, and then have more details for the device like time="12:00", below that location="london" etc., at the moment I'm just intending on using name= Devices[0].deviceName, but I do intend to include more. I tried looking at the mqtt.js  docs, but they aren't very helpful

Comment: So this sounds like it's a question about how MQTT Explorer shows/handles retained messages more than anything else.